# Konzessive Satzverbindung: Unterschied von "aber" und "trotzdem"

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

Ich habe folgende Sätze in einer Übung, wobei man zwischen a) und b) wählen muss.

1) Alain sieht alle Spiele von seiner Mannschaft St. Pauli an,

a) trotzdem gewinnt sie nicht oft.

b) aber leider gewinnt sie nicht oft.

2) Sabine Lisicki hat Spaß am Tennisspielen,

a) trotzdem muss sie jeden Tag viel trainieren.

b) aber sie trainiert jeden Tag.

Mir ist nicht klar, warum in beiden Fällen der Satz b) korrekt ist. Wäre um eine verständliche Erklärung sehr dankbar, danke.

Comment: Die Übung ist nicht sehr gut. 1) vermittelt einen wichtigen Unterschied im Deutschen, aber 2) nicht - das Weltwissen darüber, wie Freude und Aufwand normalerweise zusammenhängen, ist zu ungewiß dafür.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a suggeriert, dass man eine Mannschaft durch bloßes Zuschauen zum Sieg führen könne.

> Alain sieht alle Spiele von seiner Mannschaft St. Pauli an **(Voraussetzung erfüllt! Das müsste
>   zum Gewinnen doch eigentlich reichen!)**, trotzdem gewinnt sie nicht
>   oft.

2a suggeriert, dass jemand, der Spaß am Tennisspielen hat, nicht trainieren müsse[, er könne es ohnehin].

2b gefällt mir aber auch nicht, ergibt meines Erachtens keinen Sinn. Sinnvoll wäre:

> Sabine Lisicki hat [noch] Spaß am Tennisspielen, obwohl sie jeden Tag viel trainieren muss / obwohl sie jeden Tag trainiert.